# Error with If function in awk script

Tags: bash, if-statement, awk

Hi I've got a awk script and keep getting the error ^ syntax error.
i don't understand where it is, here is the code :

```
BEGIN { 
FS=" " 
COUNT=0 
} 

m = substr($5,4,2)
if ($6 == DAY && m == MONTH)
{
COUNT++
}

END { 
print DAY","MONTH 
}
```

here the line i write in my script using the awk file:

```
cat accident.txt | awk -v DAYS=$j -v MONTH=$i -f count-by-week-and-month.awk > $i.txt
```

Comment: What is the exact error message you're getting?

Answer (score 2):

You have some error with `{}`, try this:

```
BEGIN { 
FS=" " 
COUNT=0 
} 

{
m = substr($5,4,2)
if ($6 == DAY && m == MONTH)
    COUNT++
}

END { 
print DAY","MONTH 
}
```

Shorten version (begin block is not needed.  FS is default space, and counter is zero)

```
{ m=substr($5,4,2)
if ($6 == DAY && m == MONTH)
    COUNT++}
END { 
    print DAY","MONTH}
```

Comment: The `if` needs to be within brackets.  You could even shorten it some to what I have added.